# Запуск программы с mpi на двух и более машинах

Tags: mpi, c++, linux

Всем доброго времени суток. Подскажите, есть у меня программа с использованием технологии mpi, представленной в виде mpich2. Так вот как запустить данную программу на двух и более машинах? На одном узле запускаю так:

```
mpirun.mpich2 -l -n 4 ./myprog
```

А как на нескольких узлах запустить - я без понятия...

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](http://caps.iafe.uba.ar/roll-documentation/hpc/5.1/using-mpirun-ethernet.html) пример.

Answer (score 2):

В интернете полно информации на эту тему :)

Вот к примеру: [MpichCluster](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MpichCluster)